# Is SWF support for getimagesize() removed in PHP 7.3?

Tags: php, php-7.3

I've recently updated from PHP 7.1 to 7.3 and now some code I had to determine the dimensions of SWF files is no longer working. For example:

```
<?php
$size = getimagesize("movie.swf");
print_r($size);
?>
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 13
    [3] => width="0" height="0"
    [mime] => application/x-shockwave-flash
)
```

The fact it's got the MIME type suggests it's reading the file just fine, but no longer provides the dimensions, but I can't find any release notes or documentation to suggest the functionality has been removed, nor can I find anyone having the same problem.

I can fully appreciate why this feature would be removed, I'm not looking for a lecture on how I shouldn't be working with Flash any more. My question is whether this is the same for everyone or whether it's an issue on my end?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have gd installed

Comment: I do, the function works fine for other formats

Comment: It become like this since 7.2 not 7.3 but I can't find the reference.